# 'in-place' string modifications in Python

Tags: python, string

In Python, strings are immutable.

What is the standard idiom to walk through a string character-by-character and modify it?

The only methods I can think of are some genuinely stanky hacks related to joining against a result string.

--

In C:

```
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
{
   s[i] = F(s[i]);
}
```

This is *super* expressive and says exactly what I am doing. That is what I am looking for.

Comment: I guess since they are immutable you can't "modify it"... do you mean constructing a new string char-by-char?

Comment: This is really rare.  Can you give a context or a use case for doing this?

Comment: Adding noise to a message for testing.

Comment: @Paul Nathan: "Adding noise to a message"?  As in "replacing characters at random"?  What's wrong with `replace` for this?

Comment: @S.Lott: Replace selects against pre-known elements in the list ``mystring.replace("1", "i")`; whereas I want to iterate by index - I don't know what elements will be in the list per se. (Why does this have to be such a pain?)

Comment: @Paul Nathan: Okay.  You're making substitutions by position.  That's not clear, because the original C code is unclear.  In C there are so many limitations and quirks that it's hard to tell what's essential and what's just C quirkiness in your code sample.  "Why does this have to be such a pain?"?  What?  Why does what have to be such a pain?  I don't understand that part of your comment.

Answer (score 25):

Don't use a string, use something mutable like bytearray:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

s = bytearray("my dog has fleas")
for n in xrange(len(s)):
    s[n] = chr(s[n]).upper()
print s
```

Results in:

```
MY DOG HAS FLEAS
```

Edit:

Since this is a `bytearray`, you aren't (necessarily) working with *characters*. You're working with *bytes*. So this works too:

```
s = bytearray("\x81\x82\x83")
for n in xrange(len(s)):
    s[n] = s[n] + 1
print repr(s)
```

gives:

```
bytearray(b'\x82\x83\x84')
```

If you want to modify characters in a Unicode string, you'd maybe want to work with [`memoryview`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview-type), though that doesn't support Unicode directly.

Comment: They aren't Characters, however, just bytes.  Works only for ASCII, not Unicode.

Comment: Works for valid *bytes*, not just ASCII.

Answer (score 19):

The Python analog of your C:

```
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
{
   s[i] = F(s[i]);
}
```

would be:

```
s = "".join(F(c) for c in s)
```

which is also very expressive.  It says exactly what is happening, but in a functional style rather than a procedural style.

Comment: Interesting; I sort of like it, except for the null string. Probably as good as I'm getting though.

Comment: @Joe Koberg: A significant part of the Python is that it's shorter and more clear.  "in place" is limiting because you can't make the string longer.

Comment: I understand that, but the OP seemed to be focusing on it.  And rejected many standard python string transformation methods.  That it didn't work in-place was the only thing left.

Comment: Isn't `map()` the same as the list comprehension and join?

Comment: @javier: map() applies a function to a list of values, and returns the list of results.

Comment: @JavierBadia: map() is also less performant unless you're using built-in functions, as a rule.

Comment: While this is in place, I believe the `join` creates a temporary variable of the same size as `s` first, before it is assigned to `s`, hence any memory benefit from in-place manipulation is lost.  As opposed to the C implementation where the memory overhead is only of size `char`

Answer (score 11):

you can use the UserString module:

```
 >>> import UserString
... s = UserString.MutableString('Python')
... print s
Python
>>> s[0] = 'c'
>>> print s
cython
```

Comment: Note that MutableString was deprecated in Python 2.6 and removed in Python 3 - https://docs.python.org/2/library/userdict.html#UserString.MutableString

Answer (score 7):

I'd say the most Pythonic way is to use [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map):

```
s = map(func, s) # func has been applied to every character in s
```

This is the equivalent of writing:

```
s = "".join(func(c) for c in s)
```

Comment: Minor correction/point: One still needs to re-join the returned list (/iter/map-obj in Py3+). So the above should be:

    `s = "".join(map(func, s))`

Comment: Map is possibly the least pythonic way.

Answer (score 5):

The question first states that strings are immutable and then asks for a way to change them in place. This is kind of contradictory. Anyway, as this question pops up at the top of the list when you search for "python string in-place modification", I'm adding the answer for a real in place change.

Strings seem to be immutable when you look at the methods of the string class. But no language with an interface to C can really provide immutable data types. The only question is whether you have to write C code in order to achieve the desired modification.

Here python `ctypes` is your friend. As it supports getting pointers and includes C-like memory copy functions, a python string *can* be modified in place like this:

```
s = 16 * "."
print s
ctypes.memmove(ctypes.c_char_p(s), "Replacement", 11)
print s
```

Results in:

```
................
Replacement.....
```

(Of course, you can calculate the replacement string at runtime by applying a function `F` to every character of the original string. Different ways how to do this have been shown in the previous answers.)

Note that I do not in any way encourage doing this. However, I had to write a replacement for a class that was mapped from C++ to python and included a method:

```
int readData(char* data, int length)
```

(The caller is supposed to provide memory with `length` bytes and the method then writes the available data -- up to `length` -- into that memory, returning the number of bytes written.) While this is a perfectly sensible API in C/C++, it should not have been made available as method of a python class or at least the users of the API should be made aware that they may only pass mutable byte arrays as parameter.

As you might expect, "common usage" of the method is as shown in my example (create a string and pass it together with its length as arguments). As I did not really want to write a C/C++ extension I had to come up with a solution for implementing the behavior in my replacement class using python only.

Answer (score 3):

`string.translate` is probably the closest function to what you're after.

Comment: Interesting function - what I'm looking for, however, is to be able to adjust at a given index (or return a string that has that given index modified).

Comment: no need to import from string, `str` objects have the `translate` method. It's usually handy to use `maketrans` from the `string` module though

Answer (score 2):

Strings are iterable and can be walked through like lists.  Strings also have a number of basic methods such as `.replace()` that might be what you're looking for.  All string methods return a new string. So instead of modifying the string in place you can simply replace its existing value.

```
>>> mystring = 'robot drama'
>>> mystring = mystring.replace('r', 'g')
>>> mystring
'gobot dgama'
```

Comment: Strings are *immutable* and cannot be assigned to by member.

Comment: Correct. All string operations return a copy of the input string. The variable name is NOT immutable, however, so by re-assigning a string operation to the same variable name, you are effectively "mutating" the string.

Comment: "In the gage case of altegations to a stging, which do not incgease og decgease its length, it would still be useful if one could use the slice notation fog in-place adjustments: `myStr[0:3][:] = 'new'`".replace("g","r")

Answer (score 2):

Assigning a particular character to a particular index in a string is not a particularly common operation, so if you find yourself needing to do it, think about whether there may be a better way to accomplish the task. But if you do need to, probably the most standard way would be to convert the string to a list, make your modifications, and then convert it back to a string.

```
s = 'abcdefgh'
l = list(s)
l[3] = 'r'
s2 = ''.join(l)
```

**EDIT:** As posted in bstpierre's answer, `bytearray` is probably even better for this task than `list`, as long as you're not working with Unicode strings.

```
s = 'abcdefgh'
b = bytearray(s)
b[3] = 'r'
s2 = str(b)
```

Comment: And if you are working with multibyte strings you better be careful not to chop an encoded character!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> mystring = "Th1s 1s my str1ng"
>>> mystring.replace("1", "i")
'This is my string'
```

If you want to store this *new* string you'll have to `mystring = mystring.replace("1", "i")`. This is because in Python strings are immutable.

Comment: 1: Don't use "string" as a variable name. 2: That doesn't modify the variable.

Comment: That doesn't select by index and modify it.

Comment: @Paul Nathan: Where was "by index" a requirement?

Answer (score 1):

If I ever need to do something like that I just convert it to a mutable list

For example... (though it would be easier to use sort (see second example) )

```
>>> s = "abcdfe"
>>> s = list(s)
>>> s[4] = "e"
>>> s[5] = "f"
>>> s = ''.join(s)
>>> print s
abcdef
>>>
# second example
>>> s.sort()
>>> s = ''.join(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using translate to switch "-" with "." and uppercase "a"s

```
>>> from string import maketrans
>>> trans_table = maketrans(".-a","-.A")
>>> "foo-bar.".translate(trans_table)
'foo.bAr-'
```

This is much more efficient that flipping to byte array and back if you just need to do single char replacements

Answer (score 0):

```
def modifyIdx(s, idx, newchar):
    return s[:idx] + newchar + s[idx+1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) class to receive file-like mutable interface of string.

Comment: links are broken

Answer (score 0):

I did that like this:

```
import tempfile
import shutil

...

f_old = open(input_file, 'r')
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
    for line in f_old:
        tmp.write(line.replace(old_string, new_string))
    f_old.close()
    tmp.flush()
    os.fsync(tmp)
    shutil.copy2(tmp.name, input_file)
    tmp.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's my pythonic solution for **In-place** string reversal.

Accounts for white spaces too.

**Note**: It won't match any special characters if included in input_string except for underscore ( '_' )

i/p - **"Hello World"** => o/p - **"olleH dlroW"**

```
import re

def inplace_reversal(input_string):
    
    list_of_strings = re.findall(r'\s|(\w+)',input_string)
    
    output_string= ''
    
    for string in list_of_strings:
        
        if string == '':
            
            output_string += ' '
        
        else:
            
            output_string += string[::-1]
    
    return output_string

print(inplace_reversal('__Hello__ __World__         __Hello__       __World__ '))

>>> __olleH__ __dlroW__         __olleH__       __dlroW__
```