# how to substitute part of a string in python?

Tags: python, string, substitution, substring

How to replace a set of characters inside another string in Python?

Here is what I'm trying to do: let's say I have a string 'abcdefghijkl' and want to replace the 2-d from the end symbol (k) with A. I'm getting an error:

```
>>> aa = 'abcdefghijkl'
>>> print aa[-2]
k
>>> aa[-2]='A'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    aa[-2]='A'
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

So, the question: is there an elegant way to replace (substitute) with a string symbols inside another string starting from specified position? Something like:

```
# subst(whole_string,symbols_to_substiture_with,starting_position)

>>> print aa
abcdefghijkl
>>> aa = subst(aa,'A',-2)
>>> print aa
abcdefghijAl
```

What would be a not-brute-force code for the subst?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463746/in-place-string-modifications-in-python/3463847#3463847

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If it's always the same position you're replacing, you could do something like:

```
>>> s = s[0:-2] + "A" + s[-1:]
>>> print s
abcdefghijAl
```

In the general case, you could do:

```
>>> rindex = -2 #Second to the last letter
>>> s = s[0:rindex] + "A" + s[rindex+1:]
>>> print s
abcdefghijAl
```

Edit: The **very** general case, if you just want to repeat a single letter in the replacement:

```
>>> s = "abcdefghijkl"
>>> repl_str = "A"
>>> rindex = -4 #Start at 4th character from the end
>>> repl = 3 #Replace 3 characters
>>> s = s[0:rindex] + (repl_str * repl) + s[rindex+repl:]
>>> print s
abcdefghAAAl
```

Answer (score 12):

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

This is to be expected - python strings are immutable.

One way is to do some slicing and dicing. Like this:

```
>>> aa = 'abcdefghijkl'
>>> changed  = aa[0:-2] + 'A' + aa[-1]
>>> print changed
abcdefghijAl
```

The result of the concatenation, `changed` will be another immutable string. Mind you, this is not a generic solution that fits all substitution scenarios.

Comment: You're missing the trailing 'l' character.

Answer (score 5):

You have to slice it up and instantiate a new string since strings are immutable:

```
aa = aa[:-2] + 'A' + aa[-1:]
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do this:

```
s = "abcdefghijkl"
l = list( s )
l[-2] = 'A'
s = "".join( l )
```

Strings in Python are immutable sequences - very much like tuples. You can make a list, which is mutable, from string or tuple, change relevant indexes and transform the list back into string with `join` or into `tuple` with tuple constructor.

**EDIT:** in case of strings you can use bytearray ([docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#bytearray)) type instead of `list`, which makes transforming into string possible with `str` constructor.

Also, you could implement your own or use this class from standard library: http://docs.python.org/library/userdict.html#UserString.MutableString like so:

```
>>> from UserString import MutableString
>>> s = MutableString( "zdfgzbdr " )
>>> s
'zdfgzbdr '
>>> s[1:5]
'dfgz'
>>> s[1:5] = "xxxx"
>>> s
'zxxxxbdr '
```

Sadly - `MutableString` is deprecated and not available in Py3k (you can still write your own class, I think).

Comment: Cheer up, you still have `bytearray`

Comment: @gnibbler I'm amazed. I didn't know this type exists, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To reply comment of other post:

To make three character substitution directly with strings (see also the bytearray post) you can do partition with the sequence, especially if you do not know the position without search:

```
aa = 'abcdefghijkl'
replace = 'def'
withstring = 'QRS'
newstr,found,endpart = aa.partition(replace)

if found:
    newstr+=withstring+endpart
    print newstr
else:
    print "%r string is not in %r" % (replace,aa)
```

The length of replacement does not need to match the original in this case.