# Switch chars with regex

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

Say I have something like `s='abaabbab'`. Is it possible to change this to `s='babbaaba'` using regex? I mainly want to know if this is possible, not if it is reasonable.

I thought perhaps one of these would work (having previously imported [`re`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)):

```
s='ab'
re.sub('a|b',lambda x:['b','a'][x=='a'],s)
#or maybe
re.sub(r'a|b',lambda x:['b','a'][x=='b'],s)
```

But they just result in `'bb'`.

---

I know I could replace all `a`'s with `c`'s, then replace all `b`'s with `a`'s, then replace all `c`'s with `b`'s, but this seems so long.

[gnibbler suggests this:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3463853/1896169)

```
from string import maketrans
trans_table = maketrans(".-a","-.A")
"foo-bar.".translate(trans_table)
```

But I doesn't seem to work in python 3.

Comment: Regexes are useful for defining patterns and finding things that match those patterns. A character-replacement task like this doesn't seem suited for regexes.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm mainly curious if it is possible

Comment: You are just doing simple character replacements. A regex wouldn't be shorter, would be somewhat less understable and would be slower. There's nothing wrong with using translate here.

Comment: @JonClements Okay; however, translate doesn't seem to work in python 3... (I copied that code, and I get an error)

Comment: @Quincunx Then is your question actually "I've tried this - it doesn't work on Python 3" - or is it, I *really, really* want a regex... ? If the former - you've got your answer :)

Comment: @JonClements I'm now curious if it can be done with regex

Comment: @Quincunx, I added an explanation why your regular expression code does not work.

Comment: @falsetru I noticed as soon as you did it. I'm really enjoying your answer (you give so many possibilities; now I'm understanding this a little better).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Say I have something like s='abaabbab'. Is it possible to change this to s='babbaaba' using regex? I mainly want to know if this is possible, not if it is reasonable.

Yes - but you should use the correct form of `str.translate` as pointed out by falsetru for this task...

```
import re

s = 'abaabbab'
print re.sub('[ab]', lambda L: {'a': 'b', 'b': 'a'}[L.group()], s)
# babbaaba
```

How this is works is by looking for characters (those defined between the `[]`) and upon a match, calls the replacement function (here defined by a lambda) which looks for the suitable replacement character using a dictionary.

Comment: I already understand regexes, and now I'm liking python's way of dealing with regexes and uses a lot more than Java. I mean, you can even define a function to deal with the replacements for you.

Comment: @Jon: I think it's a really bad idea to quote (parts of) the question in your answer.  One of the most important goals of this site is to maximize the signal-to-noise ratio, and quoted excerpts are almost pure noise.

Comment: @AlanMoore In 1600+ answers I don't think I've even reached double digits of quoting parts of the OP. However, I felt it important in this case as I want to make it clear that the OP requested a regex (even though they're now aware they don't really need one). This will reduce potential noise from comments saying this isn't the best approach - they don't need to do this etc... - especially if the OP gets edited at some point.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3.x, you should pass a dictionary that map unicode ordinals to unicode characters. ( [`str.translate` documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate))

```
>>> s = 'abaabbab'
>>> s.translate({ord('a'): 'b', ord('b'): 'a'})
'babbaaba'
```

### Why the re.sub code does not work?

Because a argument passed to substitution function is not a string, but [a match object](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects); Comparing a match object with a string produce `False` (`0`); the substitution returns the first item `b`.

Use [`group` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group) to get a matched string.

```
>>> s = 'ab'
>>> re.sub('[ab]', lambda x: ['b','a'][x.group() != 'a'], s)
'ba'
>>> re.sub('[ab]', lambda x: ['a', 'b'][x.group() == 'a'], s)
'ba'
>>> re.sub('[ab]', lambda x: 'ab'[x.group() == 'a'], s)
'ba'
```

Comment: [`str.translate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) in Python 2.x is similar to [`bytes.translate`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.translate) in Python 3.x.