# Python search string and replace character in next line

Tags: python, regex, sed

in a text file I want to search for a line containing specific text and at the next line I want to substitute beginning of a line with #(comment it out) inplace:

Example - before:

```
#test search 123
text to be commented out
#test 123
```

Example - wanted:

```
#test search 123
#text to be commented out
#test 123
```

I can do it via sed:

```
sed -i '/^#test search 123/!b; n; s/^/#/' test_file
```

but i was wondering if I'm able to do it natively in python.

Comment: possible duplicate of ['in-place' string modifications in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463746/in-place-string-modifications-in-python)

Comment: your sed is at least suspicious. correct will be sed -i '/pattern/ {N; s/\n/\n#/}' file. Any python solution will be longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

outfile = open('bla.txt.2', 'w')

search = "#test search 123"
flag = 0

with open('bla.txt', 'r') as f:

    for line in f:
        if flag == 1:
            mod_line = "#" + line
            outfile.write(mod_line)
            flag = 0
            continue

        outfile.write(line)
        if (search in line):
            flag = 1

outfile.close()

os.remove('bla.txt')
os.rename('bla.txt.2', 'bla.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Works!!! So there is no chance to do the editing in-place without the second temp. file?

Comment: Not really, you could look into fileinput inplace but it still creates a temp backup file, so no dice.

Answer (score 0):

Correct sed will be

```
sed -i '/pattern/ {N; s/\n/\n#/}' file
```

This which follows maybe is not most pythonic way of same, specially if import re is needed for more complicated pattern then simple string

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

pattern='some text'
f = open('input.txt', 'r')
g = open('output.txt', 'w')
l=f.readlines()
f.close()
for ind in range(len(l)):
    if pattern in l[ind]:
        l[ind+1]='#' + l[ind+1]
for field in l:
    g.write(field)
g.close()
print('Done')
```